# How can I combine these git command?

Tags: git

Commands like these:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'update'
git push
```

How can I push my code in a more simple way?

Comment: This is how you add files, commit, and push, and I actually find it simple.  What do you have in mind?

Comment: Can I set the default parameter for git add to '.', and push with a commit of 'update' directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git commit -a -m 'update'` will add all files and also performs the commit. You'll need to "Push" yourselves a bit for the code push.

PS: I would **not recommend** to do this, it kills the purpose of staging files and makes you lose control over the committed files. Also, there are chances you may commit something unwanted from your directory.

Comment: Also worth noting is that `git commit -a` doesn't match `git add .` but rather `git add -u`. But either way, it's usually wiser to keep the separate "add" and "commit" operations.